# setting a string to localdatetime in cmd prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command, command-prompt

I am getting the following exception when running:

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (`wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>NUL`) do if '.%%i.'=='.LocalDateTime.' set ldt=%%j
```

**%%i was unexpected at this time.**

The entire script I would like to run is:

```
echo Step 2 of 8: Backing up files in target directory to an archive directory with a timestamp (ldt) in the name...
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (`wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>NUL`) do if '.%%i.'=='.LocalDateTime.' set ldt=%%j
set ldt=%ldt:~0,4%-%ldt:~4,2%-%ldt:~6,2%_%ldt:~8,2%%ldt:~10,2%%ldt:~12,6%
if exist "%APPLICATION_FILES_TARGET_DIR%" xcopy "%APPLICATION_FILES_TARGET_DIR%\*.*" "%APPLICATION_FILES_ARCHIVE_DIR%_%ldt%\*.*" /e /f /y
```

I am trying to backup a directory with the name **MyDirectory** by making a full copy of it and naming it **Backup_MyDirectory_2016-02-03_112932.940**

What am I doing wrong? What is the meaning of the unexpected exception?

Comment: Weird, that should totally work. In fact, it works on my PC just fine. I notice that you haven't set `%APPLICATION_FILES_TARGET_DIR%` anywhere... I know you said that was your entire script, but is there more to your script? Is it being called by another script? Is that bit inside of another `for` loop?

Comment: I have always just done it this way. `for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set ldt=%%i`

Comment: `%%i` only works in a batch file, on the command line you have to use `%i`

Comment: @jeb you are exactly right, could you give me a source for that?

Comment: You need only look at the 3rd paragraph of the standard help (`help for` or `for /?`): *"To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead of %variable."*